# Suggest software for capturing video screen shots

Tags: video, screenshot, screen-recording

I am trying to find software for capturing high quality video screen shots.
Assume I have a 1080 pixels video song with a duration of 1 minute. And I am looking for software to capture the video frames each second. I.e., my video song will have 60 frames captured.

This facility is available in some of the media players like The KM Player & GOM player, but the frames captured are of poor quality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/):

- Free and open-source
- Runs on [Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), [Mac](http://ffmpegmac.net/) and Linux
- Allows to [split video into pictures](https://superuser.com/a/729351/116475): e.g. `ffmpeg -i input.mov -r 0.25 output_%04d.png` to get a picture every four seconds.
- Is CLI so you can batch.
- Supports most of the video formats.

Answer (score 3):

[VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) has the ability to capture snapshots with user defined formats. Choose tiff if you want no loss in quality

[image]

VLC does not have timed frame capture as far as I know, but a workaround would be to use an autoclicker ([example](http://goldensoft.org/)) to click the "Take a Snapshot" button every second after choosing View -> Advanced Controls

[image]